# Stop Doctrine querying for nextval before inserting data

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using Doctrine with a postgres database. My primary keys are setup as sequences, like so:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Thing
{
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Id()
     */
    protected $id;
```

I persist a new entity like this:

```
$thing = new Thing();
$em->persist($thing);
$em->flush();
```

When I do that, the query log shows that doctrine is calling `SELECT NEXTVAL('thing_id_seq')` to generate an ID for the new entity before doing the `INSERT` query.

If I'm inserting 100 entities it will call `SELECT NEXTVAL('thing_id_seq')` 100 times. (I know bulk inserts like that should be done directly with SQL, but you get my point.)

**Is there a way to stop Doctrine doing a separate query to generate the ID?** (and then have the id be returned by the `INSERT` query), or is that just how it works?

I imagine having postgres generate the sequence values automatically could complicate some things, I'm just wondering if it's possible / supported.

PS: I'm not using Symfony but I have used it in the past so I'd be happy with any Symfony-based answers that I can investigate.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of auto-incremented column in PostgreSQL is the "SERIAL" type. 
But most people are using sequences because it is possible to alter/reset/... sequences while you don't have much control on SERIAL type.
You can also assign a sequence nextvalue to a column default like that :

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('test_id_seq')
);
```

If you prefer to use SERIAL type for your Doctrine column, you can tag your id property with :

```
@ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
```